# Displaying selected item form combo box to data grid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am able to bind the data grid and display the selected item from the combo box to the data grid, however all of this unnecessary text also gets displayed with it [Image showing problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpO0T.png), how would I fix this?

```
tempContestant.ContestantType = CompetitortypeCB.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

Above is the code which sets the contestant type column of the datagrid to the selected item in the combo box, how would I stop the other information from also being displayed is there some sort of parameter for the ToString method which I could use as I have not been able to find any.Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please show you XAML code with this. Depending on how you have setup your application the best way to customize what data is displayed in the `Datagrid` is to bind a collection(i.g. `ObservableCollection<SomeModel>`) to your data grid.

EDIT: The type is only `UserControl` if that is what you are using. This could be `Window`. Use whatever type of Control you are using to find the `DataContext`.

In your XAML

```
 <DataGrid  CanUserDeleteRows="True" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.ObservableCollectionName, 
            RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, 
            Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" FontSize="16" >
                 <DataGrid.Columns>
                       <DataGridTextColumn Header="Variable1" Binding="{Binding Variable1Name}" FontSize="16" Width="*"/>
                       <DataGridTextColumn Header="Variable2" Binding="{Binding Variable2Name}" FontSize="16" Width="*"/>                          
                 </DataGrid.Columns>                     
</DataGrid>
```

In your `ViewModel`/`DataContext`

```
public ObservableCollection<SomeModel> ObservableCollectionName
{
     get {return _observableCollectionName; }
     set 
     {
          if(_observableCollectionName == value)
               return;
          _observableCollectionName = value;
          OnPropertyChanged("ObservableCollectionName");
     }
private ObservableCollection<SomeModel> _observableCollectionName = new ObservableCollection<SomeModel>();
```

In Your `Model`

```
Public Class SomeModel
{
    public string Variable1Name { get; set; }
    public string Variable2Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Besides that `Binding Path=DataContext.ObservableCollectionName` should be `Binding Path=ObservableCollectionName`, this will not work, because ObservableCollectionName is not a property.